# .h file not found while adding external libraries

Tags: iphone, header-files, libraries

While adding Electro Server library to my existing project (with ARC enabled), it gives me compilation error that, `.h file not found` for several files within the library.

Hence the project itself will not get compiled.

Following are the things what I have tried till now,

- Clean the project and all it's targets.
- Removed the concerned .m file from the target and adding them
  to the target again.
- Disabled `ARC` for all the external files I have added to the
  project.
- Checked for all the files are at the location where they need to be.

What else I would have missed ?? Any Idea, Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you filled the header search paths ?

[image]

Comment: No. They are blank. What should I enter to those fields?? Thanks for prompt response

Comment: the path to you .h files - thats the place Xcode will search for .h files it could not find elsewhere. Since I do not know  Electro Server library I can not be more specific - sorry.